# How do I use opencv to turn a trapezoid into a rectangle without losing detail in the original image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract some areas of an image using opencv so that I can feed these extracted images to a Machine Learning (ML) model. The segments I am extracting are trapezoid and the bounding rectangles of these trapezoids overlap each other which would confuse the ML. Because of this I am using opencv to turn the trapezoids into rectangles. My code is:

```js
const { topLeft, bottomLeft, bottomRight, topRight } = payload.sourceCorners;

const left = Math.min(topLeft.x, bottomLeft.x);
const right = Math.max(topRight.x, bottomRight.x);
const top = Math.min(topLeft.y, topRight.y);
const bottom = Math.max(bottomLeft.y, bottomRight.y);

const sourceCorners = [topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight];

const correctedWidth = right - left;
const correctedHeight = bottom - top;

// Define the destination corners for perspective correction
const dstCorners = [
    new cv.Point2(0, 0),
    new cv.Point2(correctedWidth, 0),
    new cv.Point2(0, correctedHeight),
    new cv.Point2(correctedWidth, correctedHeight),
];

// Create the perspective transform matrix
const matrix = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(
    sourceCorners.map(({ x, y }) => new cv.Point2(x, y)),
    dstCorners
);

console.log({ correctedWidth, correctedHeight, sourceCorners: payload.sourceCorners, dstCorners });

// Apply perspective correction
correctedImage = image.warpPerspective(matrix, new cv.Size(correctedWidth, correctedHeight));
```

and the console log output for the sample below:

```
{
  correctedWidth: 718,
  correctedHeight: 350,
  sourceCorners: {
    topLeft: { x: 530, y: 460 },
    topRight: { x: 650, y: 450 },
    bottomLeft: { x: 215, y: 800 },
    bottomRight: { x: 933, y: 800 }
  },
  dstCorners: [
    Point2 { y: 0, x: 0 },
    Point2 { y: 0, x: 718 },
    Point2 { y: 350, x: 0 },
    Point2 { y: 350, x: 718 }
  ]
}
```

this works but I am getting a lot of detail lost in the image. I think that the issue is that the far away (low detail) portions of the image are made much bigger and the nearby portions are being shrunk and detail lost. I can see why this makes sense from a perspective correction point of view but I don't really want perspective correction, I just want to turn a trapezoid into a rectangle. An exmaple using a sample image:

[image: source image]

[image: generated image]

Can I use opencv to just stretch / warp the image without doing hte perspective correction?

Comment: why warp at all? you just want different segments of the track, right? what's the harm in leaving the track segments looking trapezoidal? -- if you want a proper top-down view, this *requires* a homography. an affine warp can't do it. -- you could calculate the maps for a bilinear warp (that simple stretches the image horizontally, differing along Y) and then apply remap(). that too will distort unreasonably. -- *or* map to a rectangle that is ***very tall***, so the near points don't get squished as much.